# Vue computed doesn`t calculate every time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have bug in my script and I do not know how to solve that.

I have

```
    template:   
<div v-if="!isNeed">
<label class="is-radio" >
<input type="radio" @click="fitImage(\'width\')" v-model="cropValue" name="fitter" value="width"/>
<span class="label-text">firstLine</span></label>
<label class="is-radio" ><input type="radio" @click="fitImage(\'height\')" v-model="cropValue" name="fitter" value="height"/>
<span class="label-text">secondLine</span>
</label>
</div> 
    <div v-else><span>Unsupported</span></div>
    <div class="imgscale-bottom">
    <a class="complete-image" @click="saveImage"><span>Accept</span></a>
    <a @click="deleteImage"><span class="icon-bin"></span><span>Del</span></a></div>
</div>,

computed: {
    isNeed: function () {
        if (this.currentFieldId) {
            var field = Fields.getField(this.currentFieldId);
            return field.format.toUpperCase() === 'GOOD';
        }
        return false;
    }
},
imageSelected: function (event) {
       
        var _this = this;
        if (format.toUpperCase() === 'GOOD') { 
            fieldService.saveImage(htmlId, file, format);
        } else if (isValidImageExtension(format)) {
            checkImageSize(htmlId, file, format)
   .done(function (htmlId, file, format) {
        fieldService.saveImage(htmlId, file, format);
            });
        }
    }
```

and something other code :)

When I try to upload an Image, I can see the picture which you see, with some Dialog below. And If I  upload new image without clicking on any place on the page my computed method "isNeed" wouldn't update.
It doesn't matter whether click to firstLine/secondLine/Accept/Del while do not click on free place on the page.

How to make isNeed updateble after image loading?

[image]

Comment: What is `Fields`? Does not look like `Fields` is a Vue related class/namespace, so how should Vue know when the value of that Field changed?

Comment: Fields it's an JS object. Which have Field's value

Comment: Ok but how should Vue know when the value of Filed changes? `computed` values only work properly if the result is based only properties that are know to Vue, because the result is cached, and the cache if only invalided if one of the properties that where use while the results was created has changed. So in your case  the computed value will only be updated if `currentFieldId` changes. `Fields` is completely unknown to and it cannot know when the value of that field changed.

Comment: When I press on the field with htmlId = CurrentFieldId and it happens ImageSeoected event  the property isNeed changes. But it happens only when I press on image. So

Comment: So 1)I press on the image and it opens window where I chose image. 2) When I chose image and press OK that windows closes,it uploads to the server and opens help/context Dialog below the image. 3) When I select "upload new image" it uploads but context Dialog doesn't change. To change it,firstly I need to click on the free place on the page ,then again steps 1-3 and Dialog will be updated

Answer (score 0):

`isNeed` is a computed property that is dependent on `this.currentFieldId`, is means that `isNeed` value is recomputed when `this.currentFieldId` changes.

Therefore you may try to change value of `this.currentFieldId` after an image is uploaded.

Comment: So, should I replace my template to vue script where I upload image?

Comment: If it is Yes, it is impossible,because I upload image inside that script